# OnePlus IMEI issue

Tags: android

I want to get IMEI for an android device, I get it(IMEI) very well for all other android devices but for the OnePlus(OnePlus6) have a problem.OnePlus(OnePlus6) shows different IMEI each time when I try to get it through programmatically(*#06# also shows different IMEI).so how to resolve the problem would be really helpful to me.

Comment: `getUUID(this)` I guess will return unique instance Id and not IMEI number. Also post API 29 i.e. Android 10 there is restriction on accessing IMEI number. You can find more [info here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids)

Comment: If you want of find unique DEVICE ID then [kindly read this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#best-practices-android-identifiers)